# Unable to run flutter app after android studio upgrade

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

After updating `android studio` with the latest patch (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1), am unable to run any flutter app on my emulator. This is really annoying as I have been unable to work with my flutter apps for hours now. I have tried various solutions like downgrading `JDK` to version 11 but same result.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @6c74731c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```